# SQL StoredProc Inexplicably Not Seeing Param

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have never had this much trouble with a stored procedure. I am using C#/ADO.NET as follows:

```
SqlConnection gconn = new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddCustomerComments", gconn);

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@surveyId", 
SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 250);
param.Value = SurveyId;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Stepping through all the values from end to end everything adds up and holds. The error that I'm getting is that `@surveyId` is not supplied. But it is there.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[AddCustomerComments]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @surveyId uniqueidentifier, 
    @comment varchar(250)
AS

-- Insert statements for procedure here
insert into SurveyAddendums (SurveyId, CustomerComment, RCFollowUp, RCViewed) 
values (@surveyId, @comment, 0, 0);
```

Only other things that might influence this is that `SurveyId` is a *Guid*.

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: You need to set `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Yep, just saw it after I posted the question. Ughhhh

Comment: The error message isn't very clear...

Comment: @Matt SQL and Web developments are two of the most "gratifying" areas of programming... and in college, I'd made up my mind I'd avoid both of them like a plague... but then, I got hired. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the misleading error is because you are incorrectly setting the length of the `UniqueIdentifier` field to 250, so it doesn't match.

Also, since you have no default value (making it required), you need to pass the `@comment` parameter as well.

```
SqlConnection gconn = new SqlConnection(connection);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddCustomerComments", gconn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

SqlParameter surveyIdParam = new SqlParameter("@surveyId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
SqlParameter commentParam = new SqlParameter("@comment ", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 250);

surveyIdParam.Value = SurveyId;
commentParam.Value = "This is the comment";

cmd.Parameters.Add(surveyIdParam);
cmd.Parameters.Add(commentParam);
```

Finally, you need to set `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` for a stored procedure.